How to make HTTP OPTIONS responses working for WebDAV with Apache2?
The HTTP OPTIONS request is an HTTP request type (like GET, POST) to web servers. It is optional as a helper, you can use it to programmatically find out what requests web servers understand. But you don't have to. The response to such a request should be a 200 OK with an empty body, and a header that says which requests are allowed.
With WebDAV, some applications (here specifically the WinSCP client) make OPTIONS requests, other clients don't necessarily, it varies.
I use Apache2 with mod_dav as a web server, using LDAP for authentication. WebDAV and authentication work with WebDAV clients that don't make an OPTIONS request and immediately start WebDAV communication with the PROPFIND request. Tested, OK. So, there is no authentication problem here. Only when you come with WinSCP do you get authentication errors. This is because WinSCP starts with an OPTIONS query and Apache2 responds with an error. (Unfortunately, our users have WinSCP as their tool of choice and are trained to use it, so I would like to get it working.)
This is my conf-enabled/webdav-john.doe.conf file:
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
   DavLockDB /usr/local/kitodo/webdav/DavLockDB
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dav.c>
   LimitXMLRequestBody 10240
   LimitRequestBody 0

   BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
   BrowserMatch "^Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir" redirect-carefully

   Alias /webdav/john.doe "/usr/local/webdav/users/john.doe"

   <Directory /usr/local/webdav/users/john.doe>
      Dav on

      AddDefaultCharset utf-8
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "john.doe WebDAV realm"

      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://localhost/ou=users,dc=nodomain"

      BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
      BrowserMatch "^Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir" redirect-carefully

      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all

      <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
         Require user john.doe
      </LimitExcept>

   </Directory>
</IfModule>

This produces the following result:
admin@host:/home/admin# curl -i -X OPTIONS localhost/webdav/john.doe/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024 12:38:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 456
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

If I remove the three <LimitExcept OPTIONS> ... </LimitExcept> lines, it produces the following result:
admin@host:/home/admin# curl -i -X OPTIONS localhost/webdav/john.doe
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2024 12:36:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 274
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>

So, there are two problems here: Firstly, <LimitExcept> has no effect, otherwise both attempts should produce the same result, and secondly, OPTIONS does not work. I don't know if it should work and is natively supported by mod_dav, or does it require an additional separate configuration, and if so, which one? I couldn't find anything about this anywhere. Other (non-WebDAV) pages on the server also do not respond properly to OPTIONS, but act like GET.
What does the correct configuration have to look like to enable WebDAV clients like WinSCP, that require the HTTP OPTIONS to respond properly, with Apache2 for WebDAV uploads?
